# Post ArrayList to PHP and add it to MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql, kotlin

I am creating an app similar to those from online stores

I did an ArrayList for products added to the shopping cart.
How I must do to send this into my PHP script and add this to MySQL database.

I tried return count of my ArrayList elements, but I can't.

This is PHP code:

```
<?php
$postedArray = $_POST["arrayToPOST"];
$response = array();

if(isset($postedArray))
{
    $count = count($postedArray);
    $response["Count"] = $count;
    $response["postedArray"] = $postedArray;

}
else
{
    $response["Count"] = 0;
    $response["postedArray"] = "ERROR ON POST";
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

This is my function in Android app:

```
val arrayList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()

    arrayList.add("First value")
    arrayList.add("Second value")
    arrayList.add("Third value")

    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()


    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.100.11/")
        .build()

    val webAPIInterface = retrofit.create(WebAPIInterface::class.java)


    var call = webAPIInterface.postData(arrayList)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponsePOJO> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponsePOJO>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Retrofit 2 ERROR: "+t.toString())

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponsePOJO>?, response: Response<ResponsePOJO>?)
        {
            Log.v("MainActivity", "RESPONSE: "+response!!.body().toString())

            if(response!!.isSuccessful)
            {
                Log.v("MainActivity", "Response is successful")


                Log.v("MainActivity", "")


            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Response isnt successful")
            }

        }

    })
```

I looking for solution in internet, but I found nothing.
Please help !

Comment: Does Log.e and Log.v output something?

Comment: E/MainActivity: Retrofit 2 ERROR: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: You aren't sending the data in the format you expect on the backend side.